# Change JVM JIT Options at runtime

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

Is it possible to change options and/or modes of Java JVM (JIT) at runtime? E.g. change XX:CompileThreshold, or even switch between interpreted and compiled code (`-Xcomp` vs `-Xint`).

My JVM is from OpenJDK (1.6), Hotspot or Zero/Shark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the JVM mode at runtime, however you can modify some flags without restarting the JVM. Just connect to the JVM using a JMX client (like VisualVM) and use the operation `setVMOption` of `com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic`.

For instance, if you want to enable detailed GC logging without restarting the JVM, call the method `setVMOptions("PrintGCDetails", "true")`.

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#setVMOption%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Hope that helps !

Comment: Can I change at runtime the JVM Mode: Interpreter or JIT; or some JIT heuristics (e.g. -XX:CompileThreshold)?

Answer (score 3):

You can change some of those settings through [MBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).

Most of them are read-only though.

Comment: Do you have any links to Sun/Oracle site?

Comment: And you are sure that jvm options can't be changed at runtime?

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754077/setting-jvm-parameters-at-runtime suggests that com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean#setVMOption(String, String) could help you. But in general I wouldn't rely on it.