# Modify JVM flags at Runtime

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to modify/set JVM flags as soon as my program starts. I cannot do it on the command line, because I work with people who don't even know that exists. So it has to be automatically done in the program.

I am particularly interested by these three flags: `-Xms4G  -Xmx8G -noverify`

I found in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754077/setting-jvm-parameters-at-runtime) (or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860029/change-jvm-jit-options-at-runtime)) that it is possible to modify some flags using the [Interface HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html). And [this code](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=openjdk8-jdk-master/test/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean/SetAllVMOptions.java) shows how to modify the flags. Unfortunately, the flags `Xms` or just `ms` are not recognized and then an exception is thrown.

I've also found that [capsule](http://www.capsule.io) may do the work, but it seems pretty heavy to use.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: I would say you can't. But you could start a second jvm from your code with the desired parameters using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I am not sure how it would work. Start an other JVM ok, but my program would have had already started on the first one. How can I make it switch on the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write two programs: one that is just a launcher to provide the correct parameters to run your other program.  This is how Eclipse works, and [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org), and the now-end-of-life InstallShield Multiplatform launchers.  It may be that you can write a trivial (eg one line or close to it) shell, .bat, or VBS script to do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I have to create a first very simple executable jar file, called let's say Launcher, that is going to start a second executable jar file but with all the required argument. So in my case `java -noverify -Xms4G -Xmx8G -jar MyMainJar.jar`. Am I correct? If yes, would you know the command to start just a command?

Comment: Btw, I said jar launcher, because the soft has to be multi-plateforms.

Comment: Yes, you can write the launcher program in Java. (that is how the InstallShield Multiplatform launchers are)  You can use [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) or for more control [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look into it asap, and I'll let your know!