# Setting default arguments on JVM

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, javafx-8, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing a javafx app for an embledded system. (WIN 7 EMB, JAVA 8)

this system is touch (no keyboard) but JVM does not set by default virtual keyboard

how can i set once and definitively this arguments on JVM ?

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx
```

thanks for help!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754077/setting-jvm-parameters-at-runtime

Comment: Ty mate... but i've done a search before post.... this solution does not work! i will  problably solve this using an external launcher...

Comment: Can you confirm the main method is indeed being called? IIRC in some cases the JVM may skip the `main` method if the main class extends `Application`. See e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm (last bullet before fig. 3-1) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624 (under "Description")

Comment: Confirmed, i found the solution by wrapping my main, i will post the solution by myself

Comment: it's a fake, already found solution works well from IDE (eclipse) but not from jar executable

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX doesn't initialize until `Application.launch(...)` is called.
You should try to set system properties, for example, in your `main(String[] args)` method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "true");
    launch(args); // launch JavaFX
}
```

Comment: Hi turikhay, sry but don't work on java 8, i'm not sure but i think cause jvm need this params BEFORE start the main..... this is my main -> it dont work 
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
   System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
   System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "true");
  launch(args);
  
  
 }

Comment: It has! just i need 2 main for let it work good... one for start the sencond main after set the JVM settings

Answer (score 0):

At last, i've found a similar solution, wrapping my main in another one that set jvm prop before launching my original main

```
 package launcher;

import application.Main;

public class myLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Main.main(null);

    }

}
```

and this is the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
            System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
            System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
            launch(args);
            }
```

(is necessary to flag->"Extract required libs in generated jar" on jar exportation for work!)

I'm sorry but i dont have a clear explanation for this solution!

Comment: Is there really a need to find the method via reflection? Seems overly complex and error-prone, especially since the class is hard-coded. Why not just call `application.Main.main(arguments)`?

Comment: This is a good idea, in any case i've another problem... virtual keyboard starts well by IDE but not from jar.... this is frustrating...

Comment: Another update: after start app via prompt i've intercetted this exception-->images/vk-light.png Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Image cannot be null --> seems like dont find an image for virtual keyboard

Comment: Finally, whit the flag "Extract required libs in generated jar" it works! i will spend 1 more day for test and will refactor this post... i think that jvm got problem to resolve uri of Virtual Keyboard imgs (but i'm not sure)